Communicating between Components and systems: ScriptableObject vs MonoBehavior vs Events
could you please guide me or help with sane architecture basics in Unity?
I'm making a tower defense game and I'd like to have modular approach without using frameworks, so no ECS/DOTS/SOAP
I want to have multiple components like HealthComponent, GridComponent (for entities on grid), MoveComponent etc.
I also (preferrably) want to have some Systems/Managers. GridSystem to track things on my grid, TargetingSystem to manage player targeting something.
Now I've been googling patterns for several days and identified 3 approaches/principles which are good me:

Have Systems/Managers as GameObjects and link Components to them.
So in my GridComponent I'll have [SerializeField] public GridSystem gridSystem;

Pros: It's simple, all systems are refreshed between scenes.
Cons: I cannot set these systems in prefabs and when I dynamically instantiate my Components, I have to make sure they have non-null systems.

Have Systems/Managers as ScriptableObject instances

Pros: Now my prefabs can have links to these systems and I can override them in a scene
Cons:

I've heard ScriptableObjects sometimes could retain their state between scenes/reloads
I don't know how to link these systems to Scene.
Like if my GridSystem wants to link to an actual grid in scene


Communicate through EventBus

Pros: Maximum decoupling
Cons:

It's very hard to trace what component sent what message and what systems responded.
Also it'll be hard to get overall structure when looking at code.

I also know I could make my systems as singletons, but don't want it, as I want modularity.
Could you please guide me what approach I should use or maybe propose a different one?

EDIT, example scene as requested in comments. Please note I need general knowledge and guidance rather than advice how to do this specific scene only:

Single "Level" GameObject with Grid, GridSystem, Level components.
Single "TargetingSystem" GameObject with TargetingSystem component
Single "WaveSystem" GameObject with WaveSystem component
Multiple pre-placed MobPrefabs, aka mobs on this level from start.
Also I have MobPrefab out of scene with MobPrefab, GridComponent and TargetableComponent components.
These components, need to communicate with GridSystem and TargetingSystem

GridSystem uses Grid to store entities by tile, grid traversing and so on
TargetingSystem is responsible for player input and building/abilities targeting.
WaveSystem is responsible for spawning more mobs
Problems with my approaches:
Approach #1: (Systems as MonoBehaviors)
Since my Systems are on scene and my Mob is in Prefab folder, I can't link them in editor.
When I dynamically Instantiate mobPrefab, I have to fill systems in components manually or rely on scene structure.
Approach #2: (Systems as ScriptableObjects)
I'll link my Systems to Mob prefab, however now these Systems cannot get the scene and be freshly reloaded for a new scene.
Approach #3: (Systems as MonoBehaviors + EventBus)
So I have Singleton/Static EventBus, to which I bind both MobPrefab and my GameObject systems.
class GridComponent:MonoBehaviour {
  [SerializeField] Vector2Int gridPos = Vector2Int.zero;
  void Awake() {
    EventBus.GridComponentAdded.Invoke(this)
  }

  void OnMove(Vector2Int newPosition) {
    EventBus.GridComponentMoved.Invoke(this, newPosition)
  }
}

class GridSystem:MonoBehaviour {
  Dictionary<Vector2Int, List<GridComponent>> entities = new();
  void Awake() {
    EventBus.GridComponentAdded.AddListener(component => {
      entities.Add(component.gridPos, gridEntity)
    })
    EventBus.GridComponentMoved.AddListener(component => {
      ...
    })
  }
}

This looks like the valid approach, however my EventBus will be polluted by "XComponentAdded, XComponentRemoved, XComponentHasAMessage, TargetingSystemOnTarget, GridComponentOnMove" numerous events.
Approach #4: (Systems as MonoBehaviors + EventBus hardlinking)
Maybe I should go with Approach #3, but make only "added/removed events" and set these systems there? like
class GridComponent:MonoBehaviour {
  [SerializeField] Vector2Int gridPos = Vector2Int.zero;
  [SerializeField] GridSystem gridSystem;
  void Awake() {
    EventBus.GridComponentAdded.Invoke(this)
  }

  void OnMove(Vector2Int newPosition) {
    gridSystem.OnMove(this, newPosition)
  }
}

class GridSystem:MonoBehaviour {
  Dictionary<Vector2Int, List<GridComponent>> entities = new();
  void Awake() {
    EventBus.GridComponentAdded().AddListener(component => {
      component.gridSystem = this
    })
  }
  void OnMove() {
    ...
  }
}

This way I still have hardlinking on systems/components, however I'll need to create a lot of boilerplate. I feel like this is a start of my own IoC Container. It might be bugged if existing Mobs register after System
EDIT 2:
I've come to realize when I use eventbus for Approach #4, I actually use bad ServiceLocator via events.
Approach #5: ServiceLocator
class GridComponent:MonoBehaviour {
  [SerializeField] Vector2Int gridPos = Vector2Int.zero;
  [SerializeField] GridSystem gridSystem;
  void Awake() {
    // Singleton or find game object, whatever
    ServiceLocator serviceLocator = GetServiceLocator() 
    gridSystem = serviceLocator.gridSystem()
    // Or, mimic unity: serviceLocator.GetComponent<GridSystem>();
  }

  void OnMove(Vector2Int newPosition) {
    gridSystem.OnMove(this, newPosition)
  }
}

class GridSystem:MonoBehaviour {
  Dictionary<Vector2Int, List<GridComponent>> entities = new();
  void Awake() {
    // Somehow this should be earlier than any mobs Awake()
    serviceLocator.SetComponent<GridSystem>(this);
  }
  void OnMove() {
    ...
  }
}
```


"Cons: I cannot set these systems in prefabs" why not? We might be able to help you solve that con. Can you also show an example where making sure the system is non-null is difficult when dynamically instantiating a component? We may be able to ease that too.

I cannot link my prefabs in prefab folder with Systems in scene in editor.
If I do it in code via gridSystem = GetComponentInParent<GridSystem>(), I have to pray there's a parent with GridSystem component or I get error in real time
If I do via "FindObjectsOfType" to search for any GridSystem, this is also bad because if I happen to have 2 GridSystems, I wouldn't control to which one my component is connected to.

You can always use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html to make sure that on your object is the needed one. ScriptableObject are better used as holders for stats like how much total life your enemy has, speed, etc. If you change the values, they stay changed

I don't think RequireComponent is a case in my example. I need GridSystem on a different component, therefore I cannot use RequireComponent.

It is mainly a thing for setting up the game/ level. Some things will always be in the level and should not make you much of a problem. I'm currently using a mix of your 1 & 3. The events can be great but take some time to get used to. And usually systems/ managers are singletons. You do not need two managers for the same thing in your scene

I think I'm getting a sense of your general problem space. To help make answers more concrete and applicable to your needs, could you edit your question to walk us through a sample scene? What systems does it need, what needs to be spawned dynamically vs. can be pre-configured in the scene, what spawns what, and what needs a reference to what? With this kind of detail, answers can propose a specific implementation that serves those needs.

@DMGregory I need general knowledge and guidance rather than advice how to do specific scene. I'm afraid example scene would give me answers like "hey just make a pair of singletons and call it a day". What I want is to make my basics good so I will extend this in all directions. I've added an example

For example the TargetingSystem I would solve like this: Your enemies get either an interface or component ITargetable. In your targetingSystem script and with a simple collider you can just check on the collision enter if the other one has the ITargetable and if yes, add it to some interal list of TargetingSystem. In your tower shooting component you request or get the enemy matching directly from TargetingSystem (like closest, most hp, etc). Enemies do not need to communicate with the tower, there is no linking done. If they are in range of tower (collider), they get targeted.

@Zibelas ScriptableObjects can be used for global systems that do not require the functionality of a MonoBehaviour or don't need to be in a scene. For example, I often build my spawn pools as ScriptableObjects, so a spawn pool can be referenced from different scenes and prefabs.

@Zibelas my question is all about how generally should "tower shooting component" communicate with some arbitrary "TargetingSystem". I'm lost how to build extensible, testable and modular architecture where my shooting component would "just request" TargetingSystem.

Unfortunately there's no universal best approach. As you've observed in your question, each system architecture has strengths and weaknesses. Trying to apply a single approach throughout your entire game is going to lead to awkward compromises and issues with maintainability.
I evaluate each system that I am building on a case-by-case basis. Generally, I use a simple set of questions to determine how to approach the system.

Does the system need to have awareness of objects in the scene?


Yes: build the system as a MonoBehavior.
No: proceed to #2.


Does the system need to directly reference any Unity assets in the project?


Yes: build the system as a Scriptable Object.
No: build the system as a standard C# class and access it with a service locator.

Whether to make a system a singleton is really a minor implementation detail. For MonoBehaviours and standard C# classes, I'll make the system a singleton if there is guaranteed to never be more than one instance active at a time (which is true of most systems in games in my experience). Some people will tell you that singletons are bad and you should never use them, but I've almost never found them to be a problem in Unity (note that the Unity team makes regular use of singletons, such as EventSystem.current, in Unity's APIs!).
Referencing and communicating with systems
This is a very complex and tricky subject. There are many way to get information to and from a system, each with tradeoffs. Again, there's no single right answer for all situations; however, try not to use all of these approaches in one project, or it will be hard to keep track of all of the different methods of communication used!
Serialized references
e.g. [SerializeField] private GridSystem gridSystem;
Pros

Easy to set up.
Performant.
Once the code is in place, references can be connected in the Unity Editor by someone who isn't a coder.

Cons

Creates coupling.
Can be difficult to maintain if you replace an object and have to update dozens of references to it.
A prefab or ScriptableObject can't have a serialized reference to any object in a scene.

Singletons
e.g. GridSystem.Instance
Pros

Easy to access from anywhere.
Performant.
Easy to follow in your code.

Cons

Creates coupling.
Can only be referenced in scripts, not in the Editor.
You sometimes have to be careful about initialization order.

Searching the scene
e.g. GameObject.FindAnyObjectByType<GridSystem>();
Pros

Easier to set up than singletons

Cons

Relatively slow. Never search repeatedly for the same object (e.g. in an Update script).
It can be harder to find and understand dependencies.
May not behave as expected if there are multiple objects of the same type in a scene.
Can only be used in scripts, not in the Editor.

Persistent event listeners
These are event listeners that have been added to events in the Unity Editor UI (as opposed to in code).
Pros

Little or no coupling - the scripts don't need to be aware of each other, although the component/Scriptable Object that is receiving the event must have a function with the correct parameter types (if applicable)
Can be set up in the Unity Editor by someone who isn't a coder.

Cons

Can be time consuming to set up.
Difficult to maintain.

When we delete or replace objects, or change the signature of a function, we can end up with broken persistent event listeners with no obvious indication that there's a problem.
Makes application logic difficult to follow.
Harder to debug.



Event bus
Pros

Eliminates coupling between the dispatcher and listener.
Once event dispatching is set up, it's easy to add listeners from anywhere.

Cons

Everything is coupled to the event bus.
Can make application logic harder to follow.
Makes debugging somewhat more difficult.

